# Errors when building gdb-Insight with mingw

Tags: mingw, insight

I am trying to build Insight with mingw, but I get the following error:

```
make[4]: *** [pe-i386.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/pshek/Downloads/insight-6.8/bfd'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/pshek/Downloads/insight-6.8/bfd'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/pshek/Downloads/insight-6.8/bfd'
make[1]: [all-bfd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/pshek/Downloads/insight-6.8/bfd
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is what I've done:

Open mingw shell

cd to the source folder

./configure

make

I have tried this on both the most recent version of Insight, and a slightly older version, but I get similar error message both times.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.
You will be able to compile it using

```
./configure --disable-werror
```

instead of

```
./configure
```

If you have already configured it will not work even if you try with the necessary flags. Just download again the source and configure with the proper flags.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1876116

Answer (score -2):

Just use already builded version:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Other/UserContributed/insight/mingw-insight-6.3.exe/download

Comment: Sorry, but thats not very helpful. The question is 4 months old and explicitly asked for help with compilation.